# How do i get rows from two database tables into the same while loop?

Tags: php, loops

I have a feeling I've done this before but I can't remember exactly how it's done. This is the while loop so far:

```
include ('includes/DbCon.php');
$dir = 'images/photo/';                
$query = "select * from news";
$result = $mysqli->query ($query);
echo "<table border='0' class='newsTable' style='width:70%;margin:0em auto;'>";
echo "<tr stlye='display:block;margin:0em auto;'><th>Date</th><th>Headline</th><th>Body</th><th>Image</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo date('j/M/y', strtotime($row['newsDate']));
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<a href='newsItem.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['headline']."</a>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<a href='newsItem.php?id=".$row['id']."'>" . $row['body'] . "</a>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "<p><img src=".$dir.$row['image']." width='100' height='100' alt=''>  </p>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<th colspan=\"4\"><hr width=\"90%\"></th>";
}
echo "</table>";
$mysqli->close();
```

I tried making the select statement:

```
select * from news, reviews
```

But it only brought the items from the reviews table.

I tried looking up the php manual but couldn't find it. I have to set up all the variables for the second table (reviews), don't I?

Comment: Look up joins, if you wanna pull data from more than one table.

Comment: Please show field list of both tables.

Comment: The tables are very similar. Both have these columns: id, headline, body, image. Reviews table has one extra column: link. Both tables have a date column: newsDate, reviewsDate.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct

passing multiple table name (comma separated ) bring data of all the table, but if your table have common columns then its hard to recognize them

> Best approach is [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-tables.html) and [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

other than that if you are using comma separated approach,

then see a example if you have two tables `city` and `state`

- pass the column name rather than `*` so to execute query faster
- separate duplicate column and same column with table names

> query   would be like this

```
 SELECT ct.city_name,ct.state_id,ct.is_capital,
        st.name,st.zoom,st.is_state, 
        ct.lat as ct_lat,st.lat as st_lat 
 FROM `city` as ct, 
      `state` as st
```

in your case it will be something like `news` and `review` and their *column name*

> example of join

```
 SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
             ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this soon and let you know.

Comment: I tried a join but it puts the records from the second table into the same rows as the records from the first table when it's all joined in the new table. What I'd like is to have the records from both tables have separate rows and have NULL in any fields that aren't populated.

Comment: left join and right join are used for what you want to  achieve it leave the columns blank

Comment: When I use left or right join, it still won't give the records their own rows on the new table. Could I maybe add a new id to the new table and put each record from the two tables on a separate row with a new id.

Comment: The workaround I used for this was to alter the database table and store all the records in one table instead of two. So, I just had to change the database structure and I don't need a join or union now as there's only one table.

Comment: As per your question you asked to get rid of while loop and your query had problem